# Possibility to route external site using my web server

Tags: servlets, redirect, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Probably a stupid question, or I am the stupid one.

For instance, I have a website `http://www.mysite.domain`, and another site, let's say a blog `http://www.myblog.domain`, totally different domain. I fully own both sites, however they are not physically hosted together.

Now I want to map a path of my website `blog` to the blog, and keep consistency of all further routing without redirect(keep the integrity of the original url) :

`http://www.mysite.domain/blog` ---> `http://www.myblog.domain`
`http://www.mysite.domain/blog/news` ---> `http://www.myblog.domain/news`
`http://www.mysite.domain/blog/aboutme` ---> `http://www.myblog.domain/aboutme`
`http://www.mysite.domain/blog/blog?title=whatever` ---> `http://www.myblog.domain/blog?title=whatever`

Is that an evil thought or it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the same sub-domain, this is certainly possible. You would need infrastructure and probably new hardware that routes requests to your domain. There are commercial products (https://www.a10networks.com/products/application-delivery-controllers) that can easily achieve this with some custom scripting. I am not sure about equivalent open source products.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! sadly my sites have totally different domains. I probably should describe more carefully.

Comment: Ok. If you wish to rewrite urls, you could consider apache's mod rewrite (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). There is also another small tool here (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) which is a filter written in java that can rewrite urls.